# Bind ajaxSubmit event by renderPartial

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have page with ajax-loading forms:

View:

```
$(function () {
    $('.row label').on('click', function () {
        var url = "<?php echo $this->createUrl('clientForm/getField');?>";
        var formID = "<?php echo $model->id;?>";

        var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field-name');

        if (fieldName !== undefined) {
            var callback = function (response) {
                $('body').append(response);
                LoadingLayout.hide();
            };

            LoadingLayout.show();
            $.post(url, {"fieldName": fieldName, "formID": formID}, callback);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function actionGetField()
{
    // some code
    echo $this->renderPartial('_field_form', array(
            'clientForm' => $clientForm,
            'model' => $model,
        ), true);
}
```

Controller returns me new form with CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(), but when i submit new form (that loaded by ajax) it redirects me to new page (form action="url");
I think yii cannot bind ajax-submit event handler to forms that loaded by ajax.

Any ideas how to fix it?

P.S. Yii 1.1.9

Answer (score 0):

I need to use:

```
public function actionGetField()
{
    // some code
    echo $this->renderPartial('_field_form', array(
        'clientForm' => $clientForm,
        'model' => $model,
    ), true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the $htmlOptions['live'] to true in CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton().

Comment: It set to true by default in CHtml::$liveEvents

Comment: Ok then you have to set up the event listeners in the hosting html page, that receives the ajax response.

Comment: I leave comment bellow, because find a solution. Thank you for reaction!